# Found no way to file bug report to "libnewlib-arm-none-eabi: Multilib directory structure incompatible with gcc for Ubuntu 18.04"

Tags: bug-reporting

Hy Folks,

I stumbled over the very same issue "libnewlib-arm-none-eabi: Multilib directory structure incompatible with gcc"

which has been verified to be valid also by debian guys for ubutu 18.04

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=899264

I'd like to report the bug to the ubuntu team.

Unfortunately, reporting bugs to Ubuntu seems to be *extremely* difficult. On the page 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs#Create_a_Launchpad_account

I did find absolutely no indication on how to report anything different than program crashes. Also the Debian guy in the link above did not have any clue on how to report it to Ubuntu.

Yours,

Björn

Comment: Section 6: Reporting non-crash bugs: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs#Reporting_non-crash_hardware_and_desktop_application_bugs

Comment: Also: 9: Tips and Tricks include filing bugs while headless or manually on Launchpad: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs#Tips_and_tricks